# Oil was overfilled and now has a loud ticking sound. my son says it could be pistons. Subaru 2002

Tags: oil

2002 Subaru. Had oil changed 3 days ago. Checked it today and it was overfilled. Today started loud ticking sound. My son says it could be pistons. Is it safe to drive. Is place where I had it done responsible for damage to my engine

Comment: Overfilled by several ml or a liter? A" small" overfill is no problem. At one time US car manufacturers reduced the amount of oil needed for a oil change by simply moving the fill mark on the dipstick. So you could add a quart above the "full" level with no affect in THOSE engines.